# How to use the same add() method in two different classes

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

Hi is there a way you can use the same add() method (adding things to an array) between two different classes? For example my lake class has the following add() method:

```
 public void add (Fish aCatchableThing) 
    {
        if (numThings < catchableThings.length)
        {
            catchableThings[numThings++] = aCatchableThing;
        }
    }
```

and I am trying to make it work with the following code:

```
public class FishingTestProgram3 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {

        Lake   weirdLake = new Lake(21);
        weirdLake.add(new AuroraTrout(76, 6.1f));
        weirdLake.add(new Tire());
        weirdLake.add(new Perch(32, 0.4f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(20, 0.9f));
        weirdLake.add(new Treasure());
        weirdLake.add(new Perch(30, 0.4f));
        weirdLake.add(new AtlanticWhiteFish(140, 7.4f));
        weirdLake.add(new RustyChain());
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(15, 0.3f));
        weirdLake.add(new Tire());
```

this will work(using inheritance, ie `EndangeredFish extends fish, and Perch extends EndangeredFish )` for all the fish being added however it does not workthe objects (ie. Tire, RustyChain, Treasure). The Tire, RustyChain and Treasure are classes that extend a SunkenObject class which is literally empty:

```
public abstract class SunkenObject
{


}
```

I tried creating a second add method in the lake class but that didn't work out. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how this could work? where I could add all things(ie. fish and sunkenobjects) to the same array so that when

```
public void listAllThings() 
    {
        System.out.println("  " + this + " as follows:");
        for (int i=0; i<numThings; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("    " + catchableThings[i]);
        System.out.println();
        }
```

is implemented everything in the array prints out. Thank you for your help

if any one is wondering this is the add() method I tried

```
public void add (SunkenObject sunkenObject) 
    {
        if (numThings < catchableThings.length)
        {
            catchableThings[numThings++] = sunkenObject;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you're adding both `Fish` and `SunkenObject` to `catchableThings`, then I'd advise you to keep **only one** add method. This is so as just like in a case as yours, a logical error may pop out from anywhere. **Make all fish and sunken objects inherit `CatchableThing`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is almost in the question. What you want to be able to add to the lake is not only instances of `Fish`. What you want to be able to add is a catchable thing. So you need to define such a type.

`Fish` and `SunkenObject` should thus extend a common base class named `CatchableThing`, or should implement an interface called `CatchableThing`.

And the signature of the `add()` method should be

```
public void add(CatchableThing aCatchableThing)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider programming to an interface rather than concrete types - e.g. `ICatchable`:

```
public void add(ICatchable item)
{
    // Add the catchable item to the lake.
}
```

Comment: Very minor nitpick, but interfaces generally don't start with an `I` in Java.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Thanks. No, I wouldn't say that it's necessarily "very minor". It's a fair point. Not prefixing an interface with `I` is a Java idiom; and I have brought a C# idiom to a Java party: that is a little like insisting that "Holy cow!" should be "¡Vaca santa!" in Spanish...when "¡Dios mio!" is really the idiomatic way to express the same meaning in Spanish.  Still, I will keep the `I` prefix in this case to bop the reader on the head that `ICatchable` is ideed an interface. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a common base class from which all things you would want to add are derived.